# web pack 5 configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I recently updated all my dependencies including
(Webpack 4.44 -> Webpack 5.69, react-router-dom 5 -> react-router-dom 6 and react 16 -> react 17).

I am trying to configure webpack but i am getting some error which i cannot figure out. I should mention i am trying to use the asset module of webpack 5 replacing my older loaders(url-loader, img-loader and file-loader).

But am getting the following error

> Html Webpack Plugin:   Error: Child compilation failed:   Module build
> failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):   SyntaxError:
> /Users/shahid.ahmad/src/assets/favicon-32.ico:
> Unexpected character ''. (1:0)

Also i am getting this

> ChunkRenderError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined during
> rendering of asset
> asset/resource|/Users/shahid.ahmad/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/shahid.ahmad/src/assets/favicon-32.ico

and this

> ERROR in ./src/assets/fonts/FuturaPT-Demi.otf Module build failed
> (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
> /Users/shahid.ahmad/src/assets/fonts/FuturaPT-Demi.otf:
> Unexpected character ''. (1:4)

this is what webpack config looks like

```js
const path = require('path');
const HTML = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  
  const currentPath = path.join(__dirname);
  
  const basePath = `${currentPath}/.env`;
  
  const envPath = env.environment ? `${basePath}.${env.environment}` : basePath;
  
  const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;
  
  const fileEnv = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;
  
  const envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
  
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});

  return {
    mode: env.production ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry:  { 
      application : './src/index.tsx' 
    },
    devtool: env.production ? false : 'source-map',
    cache:{
      type : 'filesystem'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.(mjs)?$/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false, 
          },
        },        
        {
          test: /.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [{
            loader : 'babel-loader'
          }],
        },
        {
          enforce: 'pre',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'source-map-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.mjs$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          type: 'javascript/auto',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
          type: 'asset/inline',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(html)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(css)$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css', '.html', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '.'), 'node_modules'],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
      publicPath: '/',      
      chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    },
    devServer: {            
      historyApiFallback: true,
      open: true,
      compress: true,
      hot: true,            
    },
    plugins: [
      new HTML({
        template: './src/template.html',
        inject: true,
        hash: true,
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
    ],
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 1,
        cacheGroups: {
          defatulVendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

I have read a lot but still not able to figure out what the problem is. any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your build fails because you do not have a loader specified for `.ico` file types.

Consider specifying a loader for it and the other static resources and update the regex to include it

```
- test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
+ test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/i,
```

Comment: I must have removed it while trying things out. I added it but i am still getting the same problem. I will update the question as well. thank you for pointing it out.